# White screen in my app with jetpack compose (android ide)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I was using Android Studio for Jetpack Compos, and now I do not have my device because I am in another country. I went to Android ide and was trying to make an application using Compos, but the expected result in both cases is a white screen. Hope help me fast to solve it
Here is my code

```
package com.example.birthdayproject

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.material3.OutlinedTextField
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.example.birthdayproject.ui.theme.MyComposeApplicationTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)


    @Composable
    fun EnterNameScreen(setName: (String) -> Unit) {
        var name by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Text(text = "Enter Birthday Person's Name:")
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
            OutlinedTextField(
                value = name,
                onValueChange = { name = it },
                label = { Text("Name") }
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
            Button(onClick = { setName(name) }) {
                Text("Show Birthday Greeting")
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun BirthdayGreeting(name: String) {
        Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                Icon(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.birthday_cake), // Replace with your icon
                    contentDescription = "Birthday Cake"
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
                Text(text = "Happy Birthday, $name!")
                // Add more birthday-themed elements here (optional)
            }
        }
    
@Override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyComposeApplicationTheme {
                var showGreeting by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
                var name by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

                if (!showGreeting) {
                    EnterNameScreen { enteredName ->
                        name = enteredName
                        showGreeting = true
                    }
                } else {
                    BirthdayGreeting(name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

And the results
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/irYgU.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irYgU.jpg)

Comment: Your code looks like a mess. please share a formatted code.

Comment: What can i do in it?

Comment: I have test your code, it working fine , i can run and see the content.
Please resart ide either clear it cache and check it again